# DES decryption of the homomorphic encryption ciphertext

Tags: public-key, homomorphic-encryption, symmetric, des, proxy-re-encryption

I implemented an application using partial homomorphic encryption for outsourced computations. To get an efficient bandwidth, I am thinking to apply (DES) symmetric algorithm to encrypt the message instead of HE before uploading it to the cloud.

Can I perform DES decryption operations (permutation and S-boxes) on homomorphic encryption ciphertext?

$
\begin{align}
&C = \operatorname{DES}(m)\\
&C'= \operatorname{FHE}(C) = \operatorname{FHE}(\operatorname{DES}(m)) \\
&\operatorname{DES}^{-1} (C' )= \operatorname{DES}^{-1} (\operatorname{FHE}(C))= \operatorname{DES}^{-1} (\operatorname{FHE}(\operatorname{DES}(m)))= \operatorname{FHE}(m)
\end{align}
$

Comment: Keep in mind that [Kreyvium](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/81189/18298) is designed from Trivium with increased security for decreasing the data sent to the cloud with FHE. Also, partial will not be enough to achieve that.

Comment: Note that there also exist (asymptotically) rate-1 FHE schemes. The relevant papers are [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/720.pdf) and [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/733).

Comment: This seems dangerous. If anybody can skip the homomorphic encryption then performing $\text{DES}^{-1}$ would directly give an adversary the plaintext. Because I presume you only store $C$ in the cloud. I don't think many FHE schemes allow for efficient bitops, and DES (decryption) is a lot of rounds with a lot of bitops.

Comment: Brainstorm: [XOR](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/30147/1172) with a key stream might be easier to perform (storing the nonce next to the ciphertext).

Comment: Besides this interesting thought experiment, I really wonder how you got to something as archaic as DES starting from FHE, by the way. It's like putting a steam locomotive in front of a TGV.